# PHP 7.2: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php

```
<?php if(count($errors) > 0) : ?> <div> <?php foreach ($errors as $error) : ?> <p><?php echo $error ?></p> <?php endforeach ?> </div> <?php endif ?>
```

Am new to PHP, trying to make a website that let you register and when I want to display that user did not fill up forms this error appear, need a solution I know that count doesn't work for this from version 7.2 of PHP but i can't figure out how to get this to work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is unclear, without a clear and well thought out question you're unlikely to get a clear and well thought out answer. Please review the SO [guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and have a quick read of [this blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) which contains a checklist of actions to take before asking a question.

Comment: You can make $error with empty array if there are no errors.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 7.2 you can do a check on your value before doing the count with [is_iterable()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-iterable.php) function. Later in PHP 7.3 you also have the [is_countable()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-countable.php) function.

Try type casting your object to an array.

```
 if (count((array) $errors) > 0)
```